# why is the Css file codes in wp child theme written as comment line?

Tags: css, child-theming

i have style.css in the wp child theme. (Below is the sample code) and this code in the comment line. as far as I know comments have no effect on the layout of a document. well, why are these codes written in the comment line??

```
/*
Theme Name:     kabasakal Childtheme
Description:    
Author:         Kabasakal Reklam Ajansı
Template:       kabasakal (you must enter the name of the main theme here!!)

*/
```

Comment: I think those lines are parsed by WP to be used as theme metadata.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe these lines are what Wordpress uses to get the metadata about a theme/file when allowing an admin to choose between themes

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/main-stylesheet-style-css/

> WordPress uses the header comment section of a style.css to display information about the theme in the Appearance (Themes) dashboard panel.

Answer (score 0):

This is a required header comment that goes at the very top of the child theme `style.css`.

> This tells WordPress basic info about the theme, including the fact that it is a child theme with a particular parent.

https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/#2-create-a-stylesheet-style-css